# Malloc execution error

Tags: c, malloc

I made this method for a test and for some reason the malloc is not working. When I comment it it does work, but otherwise it will just say the program has stopped working.

```
typedef struct {
    int NroUSP; // chave primária
    int curso;
    int estado;
    int idade;
    bool valido; // para exclusão lógica
} REGISTRO;

typedef struct s {
    int NroUSP; // chave primária
    int curso;
    int estado;
    int idade;
    bool valido;
    struct s* prox;
} NO;

typedef struct {
    NO* inicio;
} LISTA;
```

These are the structures I used ^

EDIT: THE PROBLEM WAS THIS ASTERISK RIGHT BEFORE AUX

```
void ex6(){
    REGISTRO* aux;
    FILE *arq = fopen("C:\\Users\\jujuc_000\\Desktop\\Teste\\dados.bin","rb");
    FILE *arq2 = fopen("C:\\Users\\jujuc_000\\Desktop\\Teste\\ex6.bin","wb");
    LISTA l;
    l.inicio = NULL;
    NO*p = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO)); // this is the test malloc
    if(arq){
        while(1==fread(&aux,sizeof(REGISTRO),1,arq)){
            /*p = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO)); // this is the one I want to keep
            p->NroUSP = aux->NroUSP;
            p->curso = aux->curso;
            p->estado = aux->estado;
            p->idade = aux->idade;
            p->valido = aux->valido;
            if(!l.inicio){
                l.inicio = p;
            }
            p=p->prox;*/
        }
    }

    fclose(arq);
    fclose(arq2);
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of "NO"? Also, don't cast malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc .  It's dangerous.

Comment: Is it failing at `malloc` or at `p=p->prox`?

Comment: How is it not working? If there's an error message, please include it in the question.

Comment: "THE PROBLEM WAS THIS ASTERISK RIGHT BEFORE AUX" - so precisely what Ken's answer described (sigh).

Answer (score 1):

`fread(&aux,sizeof(REGISTRO),1,arq)` is most likely your problem; `aux` is a pointer to a `REGISTRO`, but you try to read in a full `REGISTRO` into it, which more than likely overwrites memory, causing the apparent `malloc` failure in the next line. Change the declaration to:

```
REGISTRO aux;
```

And things should work.

Comment: Nope :/ still not working. Plus I tried putting the malloc both inside and outside the loop, and neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Use feof() instead of if(arq) ...
2. Set p->prox = NULL;
3. Either declare 'REGISTRO aux' or allocate memory to 'aux' if declaring it as a pointer.